# SpamAssassin local.cf DMARC configuration recognizes reject and none, but not quarantine

Tags: perl, spamassassin

For SpamAssassin 3.4.2 I've added the below configuration ruleset to `local.cf` with the intent of providing a spam score for failed DMARC tests.

The DMARC and SPF Authentication-Results headers are created by `opendmarc` and the DKIM Authentication-Results header by `opendkim`.

The expected output is a score for all three header results added to the X-Spam-Report header.

The actual output is only for a domain that has `p=reject` or `p=none` with the appropriate score added to the X-Spam-Report header, but for `p=quarantine` nothing is added to the X-Spam-Report header even though the DMARC, DKIM and SPF Authentication-Results headers have been added as expected.

Added to `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`:

```
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::AskDNS
askdns __DMARC_POLICY_NONE _dmarc._AUTHORDOMAIN_ TXT /^v=DMARC1;.*\bp=none;/
askdns __DMARC_POLICY_QUAR _dmarc._AUTHORDOMAIN_ TXT /^v=DMARC1;.*\bp=quarantine;/
askdns __DMARC_POLICY_REJECT _dmarc._AUTHORDOMAIN_ TXT /^v=DMARC1;.*\bp=reject;/

meta DMARC_REJECT !(DKIM_VALID_AU || SPF_PASS) && __DMARC_POLICY_REJECT
score DMARC_REJECT 10
meta DMARC_QUAR !(DKIM_VALID_AU || SPF_PASS) && __DMARC_POLICY_QUAR
score DMARC_QUAR 5
meta DMARC_NONE !(DKIM_VALID_AU || SPF_PASS) && __DMARC_POLICY_NONE
score DMARC_NONE 0.1
endif # Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::AskDNS
```

What is wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration you refer to is copied from Random Thoughts blog on [DMARC / Spamassassin / Qmail](https://random.sphere.ro/2019/08/12/dmarc-on-spamassassin/). This blog post gives AskDNS as a third option if you can't use OpenDMARC for some reason. As you are already using OpenDMARC, you can directly use its `Authentication-Results` header in SpamAssassin. Modified from [David Jones](http://spamassassin.1065346.n5.nabble.com/Custom-DMARC-FAIL-rule-td153847.html#a153867):

```
header DMARC_PASS Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=pass/
describe DMARC_PASS DMARC check passed
score DMARC_PASS -0.1

header DMARC_FAIL Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=fail/
describe DMARC_FAIL DMARC check failed
score DMARC_FAIL 5.0

header DMARC_NONE Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=none/
describe DMARC_NONE DMARC check neutral
score DMARC_NONE 0.1
```

If you have implemented OpenDMARC to *connection-stage reject* the messages that fail DMARC checks with `p=reject`, your SpamAssassin will never see any messages falling to the fourth category, but here it is, just for completeness:

```
header DMARC_FAIL_REJECT Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=fail \(p=reject/
describe DMARC_FAIL_REJECT DMARC check failed and the sending domains says to reject this message
score DMARC_FAIL_REJECT 10.0
```

Because the `Authentication-Results` headers can also be [forged](https://serverfault.com/q/957154/274176), I wouldn't give high *negative* score based on them alone. Therefore, the most useful rule here is the `DMARC_FAIL`, firing on `p=quarantine`. In my opinion, that could also give score more than the `5.0` in this example, as the decision is already made by the sending domain.

If the above example configuration is not suitable, here is an additional configuration and scoring option:

```
header DMARC_PASS Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=pass/
describe DMARC_PASS DMARC check passed
score DMARC_PASS -0.1

header DMARC_NONE Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=none/
describe DMARC_NONE DMARC record not found
score DMARC_NONE 0.1

header DMARC_FAIL_NONE Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=fail \(p=none/
describe DMARC_FAIL_NONE DMARC check failed (p=none)
score DMARC_FAIL_NONE 2.0

header DMARC_FAIL_QUARANTINE Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=fail \(p=quarantine/
describe DMARC_FAIL_QUARANTINE DMARC check failed (p=quarantine)
score DMARC_FAIL_QUARANTINE 5.0

header DMARC_FAIL_REJECT Authentication-Results =~ /mail\.example\.com; dmarc=fail \(p=reject/
describe DMARC_FAIL_REJECT DMARC check failed (p=reject)
score DMARC_FAIL_REJECT 10.0
```